# String count added automatically while inserting data into table wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

When I insert the serialize data in the postmeta table the data is modified while inserting like:

```
s:107:"a:4:{s:6:"page_1";s:5:"third";s:6:"page_2";s:5:"first";s:6:"page_3";s:6:"fourth";s:6:"page_4";s:5:"fifth";}";
```

but when I print this data before inserting it is displaying this that is right:

```
a:4:{s:6:"page_1";s:5:"third";s:6:"page_2";s:5:"first";s:6:"page_3";s:6:"fourth";s:6:"page_4";s:5:"fifth";}
```

while inserting it is automatically add string count  s:107:" in front of data or "; in back of data.

Please suggest me how i resolve this.

Comment: I guess it is re-serializing the data. Where is the code?

Comment: I used $page_title=maybe_serialize($val); the $val containing the array value

Comment: yes used serialize() but not worked

Comment: it is displaying Array (  [65] => 1 [849] => 2 [742] => 4 ) and i want serialize data in table